# Angularjs: Nested repeat in angular doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Following [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/987499/Nested-Ng-Repeat-on-AngularJS)

But it seemed not to work on my json structure. Here is my json

```js
$scope.trucks = [{
  id: 4,
  truckNumber: '50LD 02456',
  driverName: 'Dẻo',
  shipments: [{
    id: 1,
    routeCode: "THC-VinhHao",
    trip: 2
  }, {
    id: 2,
    routeCode: "THC-VinhHao(R)",
    trip: 3
  }, {
    id: 3,
    routeCode: "THC2-Hiệp Thành HM",
    trip: 3
  }]
}, {
  id: 5,
  truckNumber: '61C 03948',
  driverName: 'Hưng',
  shipments: [{
    id: 4,
    routeCode: "TBC-VBL HMo",
    trip: 1
  }, {
    id: 5,
    routeCode: "THC2-Hiệp Thành HM",
    trip: 4
  }]
}];
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-ng-repeat="truck in trucks">
    {{truck.truckNumber}}
    <br />
    <ul>
      <li data-np-repeat="shipment in truck.shipments">{{shipment.routeCode}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any help are appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: try using "ng-repeat", not "data-ng-repeat" or "data-np-repeat"

Comment: typo?? `np-repeat`???

Comment: `data-ng-repeat` would be fine

Comment: Here is the working example http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15706/

Comment: Thank you!!! This is my foolish fault!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you have everything correctly spelled out.  ng-repeat was misspelled.

```
<ul>
  <li data-ng-repeat="truck in trucks">
    {{truck.truckNumber}}
    <br/>
    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="shipment in truck.shipments">{{shipment.routeCode}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `ng-repeat` is still wrongly spelled in the 2nd `li` ;-)

Comment: Dammit! haha - Thanks Jordumus

Comment: No problem @Van Le, please mark the answer as correct if everything is okay with you

Answer (score 1):

```
Change np-repeat to ng-repeat then it will work.    
<ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="truck in trucks track by $index">
          {{truck.truckNumber}}
        <br />
        <ul>
          <li data-ng-repeat="shipment in truck.shipments track by $index">{{shipment.routeCode}}</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <li data-ng-repeat="truck in trucks">
    {{truck.truckNumber}}
    <br />
    <ul>
      <li data-np-repeat="shipment in truck.shipments">{{shipment.routeCode}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

There is a typo.

```
<li data-ng-repeat="shipment in truck.shipments">{{shipment.routeCode}}</li>
```